# uncaught referenceerror mostrar is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML which, as you can see, has two calls to javascript functions, it works perfectly in local but when I put it on the server I get the error on the picture. 
This is the first time that I put anything on a server and I'm really confused so I'll be really thankful for any help.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Creación de cajas</title>
        <script    
            type="text/javascript" src="codJavaScript.js">
        </script>
        <link href="../estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="menu"> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="menu.php">Inicio</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
         <form action="../Controladores/recogeDatos.php" method="post">
             <table>
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                         <p>Codigo: </p>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <input type="text" name="codigo">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <p>Anchura: </p>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <input type="text" name="anchura">
                     </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                         <p>Altura: </p>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <input type="text" name="altura">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <p>Profundidad: </p>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <input type="text" name="profundidad">
                     </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                         <p>Color: </p>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <input type="color" name="color">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <p>Tipo caja: </p>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <input type="text" name="tipoC" list="tipos" onchange="mostrar(this.value)">
                         <datalist id="tipos">
                            <option>Negra</option>
                            <option>Fuerte</option>
                            <option>Sorpresa</option>
                         </datalist>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr id="mec">
                    <td>
                        <p>Mecanismo: </p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="mecanismo">
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr id="pb">
                     <td>
                        <p>Placa base: </p>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <input type="text" name="placa">
                     </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr id="cont">
                     <td>
                        <p>Contenido:</p>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <input type="text" name="contenido">
                     </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>Estanter&iacute;a:</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="codEstant" onchange="muestraLejas(this.value)">
                        <option value="null" selected="selected">Elige Estanter&iacute;a</option>
                                                        <option value=C8>C8</option>
                                                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <p>Leja: </p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="leja" name="leja">
                            <option value="null" selected="selected">Elige Leja</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" name="creaCaja">
                    </td>
                </tr>

             </table>
        </form>
    </body>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l44wx.png)

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function muestraLejas(str){
    var xmlhttp;   
if (str=="")  {
    document.getElementById("leja").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    /* Creamos el objeto request para conexiones http,
    compatible con los navegadores descritos*/
  }
  else  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    /*Como el explorer va por su cuenta, el objeto es un ActiveX */
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  {

      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("leja").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   /*Seleccionamos el elemento que recibirá el flujo de datos*/
    }
  }
//      alert(str);
    xmlhttp.open("GET","../DAO/getLejas.php?codEstant="+str,true);
    /*Mandamos al PHP encargado de traer los datos, el valor de referencia */
//        alert(str);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }

  function mostrar(str){
      if(str==="Negra"){
          var vis=document.getElementById("pb").style.display='inline';
          var vis=document.getElementById("mec").style.display='none';
          var vis=document.getElementById("cont").style.display='none';
      }
      else if(str==="Fuerte"){
          var vis=document.getElementById("mec").style.display='inline';
          var vis=document.getElementById("pb").style.display='none';
          var vis=document.getElementById("cont").style.display='none';
      }
      else if(str==="Sorpresa"){
          var vis=document.getElementById("cont").style.display='inline';
          var vis=document.getElementById("mec").style.display='none';
          var vis=document.getElementById("pb").style.display='none';
      }
  }
```

Comment: The error in the title and the error in the picture are different.  It's important to read the actual error message.  As for the error in the picture, those functions you're calling aren't defined.  Did you forget to include `codJavaScript.js` on the server?  Does it not define those functions?

Comment: The problem is not *that* error, but the *first one* in your screen capture (Unexpected token <). You have conveniently cut the error message so that it doesn't show which file and which line throws that error.

Comment: It looks like using jQuery and has not included the library

Comment: `<option value=C8>`  should be `<option value="C8">`

Comment: It's probably loading some HTML file (these have `<`) instead of the actual JavaScript. This may be caused by server configuration or bad `.htaccess` configuration. Also make sure your JavaScript file is located in your root, or it might be a `404 Not Found` page it's loading instead of your script.

Comment: Ok, the picture and the title are fixed, sorry. I'm not using JQuery, to start with I don't even know how to use it.

Comment: @YosvelQuintero: One would think that from the question title.  However, that's not the actual error the OP is getting.  He's being misleading for some reason, which will make it difficult to receive help.

Comment: The JavasScript file is in the actual root.

Comment: @user7142440: No, it's not fixed.  The title says `$ is not defined` and the error says `mostrar is not defined`.  "$" and "mostrar" are not the same thing.  Pay attention to the *actual error message* when you receive an error.  Ignoring it will make it more difficult to resolve the problem.

Comment: So it's actually loading a `404 Not Found` instead of your script. Is your script file located in the same folder on your server as the PHP file?

Comment: Did you include the jQuery  library??

Comment: I'm not being misleading, I'm just totally confused and don't really know how to express the problem...

Comment: try adding this to the `<head>` :       `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Please all note that the first problem is that his own js file is not being loaded.

Comment: @mike510a: That won't help.

Comment: Yeah, it's on the same folder as the PHP file.

Comment: Can you also paste in the javascript file causing the error?  (and give us the full error message complete with the last part on the right that says the file and LINE causing the error?)

Comment: Please check the file not the server again. I tried and the JavaScript can't be accessed.

Comment: Do you have an `.htaccess` file?

Comment: You need a DOCTYPE header and closing HTML tag

Comment: @mike510a while that's true, it's not causing the problem at hand

Comment: and to actually upload your file to the server's HTML directory

Comment: the html HAS a doctype and a closing html tag.

Comment: No, Ties, I don't have an .htaccess file

Comment: I have just tried the project on local again and there is no problem at all...

Comment: @Ties answer is correct - the typo in the Javascript file  is causing it to try and parse the 404 HTML page\

Comment: You local machine might not be case sensitive while your server is. This can cause problems so it's advisable to use `-` in between words in file names instead of camelCase

Comment: Thank you everyone, I'm really sorry for the stupid mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: index]

I checked your files. You made a typo. 
`codJavascript.js` on server vs `codJavaScript.js` in your HTML script tag.

You should change your HTML to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="codJavascript.js"></script>
```

(With a lowercase 's')

Comment: @user7142440 no problem. Use only lower case in your file names in the future! ;)